# How to make a concept fail with a custom error message (C++20)

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, c++20, c++-concepts

Concepts are great at pinpointing an error to the line of code where *"a constraint was not satisfied"*.

I'm wondering, however, if it is possible to issue a custom informational message there. The upside of static_assert was exactly that possibility. Use case: Any library that wants to help the user in figuring out why a certain expression was not satisfying the constraints.

Here is a simple example, just to have some code. You might argue that any half-decent 'user' must be able to figure out the compiler's note *"because 'is_base_of<Base, C>' evaluated to false"*, but more custom information could not hurt. There will be more complicated concepts for sure.

```
template<typename B, typename D> 
concept is_base_of = std::is_base_of_v<B, D>;

template <typename T, is_base_of<T> BaseType>
struct BaseWrapper { };  

int main() 
{
    class Base {};
    class Derived : public Base {};
    class C {};

    using T1 = BaseWrapper<Derived,Base>;
    using T2 = BaseWrapper<C,Base>;         // fails right here, but a custom message would be nice
}
```

Comment: I can't find anything about custom messages in the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), but it would sure be a useful thing to have. The simple solution is to write a nice documentation.

Comment: What would you want for the more informative custom message?

Comment: In the case above, one could issue a simpler custom message like "B must be a base class of D". Putting the actual classes (`Base` and `C` in this case) in the custom message is an additional challenge. `static_assert` suffers from that being impossible. This complication is probably another reason why custom messages are not supported.

Comment: @churill : *The best documentation is no documentation (necessary)* - in case you haven't heard it...

Comment: @non-user38741 I think that's impractical for any larger code base, but if you think about it, the same could be said for custom diagnostics. Just name your constraint in a way that no extra custom message is required ;)

Comment: Even a large codebase should not have an excessive amount of concepts. Note that the messages are not per function, but per concept. I don't think it is asking too much of the author to put in meaningful messages for 10-30 basic concepts. I would even go so far as to require a message for each concept. (Ahead of my time, let's wait and see)

Comment: @non-user38741 Note that this Q&A has resuscitated the concept's diagnostic topic [at r/cpp](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/iixi6x/custom_diagnostics_for_concepts/). The OP of the r/cpp post says he/she does not want to attempt to drive this resuscitation, but leaves it up for any community member to do so. If you really feel this is an important feature, you may want to consider investing into this task. See my updated answer for details.

Comment: You seem like the right person for this task ;-)

Answer (score 20):

## [EWG] P1267R0: Custom Constraint Diagnostics

> I'm wondering, however, if it is possible to issue a custom informational message there.

There is currently no such native feature as part of Concepts, but there was a WG21/SD-1 paper that covered specifically this topic:

- [P1267R0: Custom Constraint Diagnostics](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1267r0.pdf)

> #### Design
>
> There is already precedent in the standard for custom diagnostics:
>
> ```
> [[deprecated("reason")]]
>
> static_assert(cond, reason)
> ```
>
> We propose adding a new attribute, similar to
> `​[[deprecated("reason")]]`​, for custom constraint diagnostic
> messages. Let’s call this new
> `attribute[[reason_not_used("reason")]]`​ for now:
>
> ```
> template​ <fixed_string Pattern>  
>   requires Correct_Regex_Syntax<Pattern>  
>   [[reason_not_used("invalid regex syntax")]]
> bool​ match(string_view sv);
> ```
>
> When this attribute is placed on a function, the diagnostic message
> would be used when:
>
> - The function was considered and rejected as a candidate for a function call, for any reason (deduction/substitution failure,
>   requires clause constraint failure, no suitable conversion, etc).
> - The function call found no matching overload and thus lead to a compilation failure.
>
> Today, when a function call fails to find a match, C++ compilers typically print out a list of all the candidates considered. We envision this new attribute as being additive to existing diagnostics, in the same way that `static_assert`​’s diagnostic message is.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Future Directions
>
> This attribute could also potentially be used on class and alias
> templates to provide custom diagnostic messages for constraint
> failures and when selecting a specialization (in the case of class
> templates):
>
> ```
> template​ <​typename​ T>  
>   requires FloatingPoint<T> || Integral<T>  
>   [[reason_not_used("the element type must be numeric")]]
> struct​ matrix {};
>
> matrix<string> a;
>
> #:#:​error: ​template constraint failure 
> matrix<string​>​ a;​
>              ^
> #:#:​note: ​constraints not satisfied: ​the element type must be numeric
> #:#:​note: ​within ...
> ```
>
> This attribute could also be attached to concept definitions, and used
> whenever checking that concept’s constraints fails.

Its audience was the *Evolution Working Group* (EWG), and according to @DavisHerring (C++ committee member), albeit not published externally, it was rejected:

> @DavisHerring:
>
> [...] that paper was considered in 2018 and “rejected”—that is, new information (like “It’s 2021 and in practice concept error messages are still bad”) would be needed to consider it again.
>
> Recently, papers have been given very brief public statuses; for older papers like this one, the references are unfortunately internal.

However, most likely inspired by this StackOverflow Q&A, the topic has resuscitated on [r/cpp](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/), as the thread [Custom 'diagnostics' for concepts](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/iixi6x/custom_diagnostics_for_concepts/), which discusses an alternative, simpler approach to custom diagnostics for concepts [**emphasis** mine]

> #### Custom 'diagnostics' for concepts
>
> I'd like to 'propose' the following simple attribute for concepts:
>
> ```
> template <typename T> [[requirement_failed("reason")]]
> concept MyConcept = /*some expression*/;
>
> template<typename T>
> concept MyConcept2 = requires(T t) {    
>     /*some expression*/;
> } [[requirement_failed("reason")]];
> ```
>
> The purpose should be quite obvious: "reason" is issued as a compiler
> note, when the requirements are not met.
>
> Notes:
>
> There is
> [P1267R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1267r0.pdf),
> but I think it's just not put or presented it in a simple enough way.
> Allowing the attribute on any definition that 'requires' will likely
> result in a mess.
>
> Allowing it on concept definitions only will keep things clean. It
> avoids duplication for various functions making use of the same
> concept. It avoids over-use of the feature, as there should not be an
> excessive amount of concepts.
>
> In my view, concepts that are part of an interface should offer
> 'diagnostic' messages as a best practice.
>
> **I don't think I have the guts, insight or time to make this into an official proposal**, even if it is a very simple thing. So I thought,
> I'd just mention it here. It's also hard to imagine that something
> similar has not been considered yet, by some concepts committee.
>
> Anyway, **I wanted to draw some attention to it.**

The author explicitly mentions he/she would not like to go forward with a formal paper on the topic. If e.g. the OP of this SO Q&A sees this as an important feature, one approach would be to pick up and (re-)formalize this topic into a paper.

Comment: Nice, but unfortunately 'diagnostics' in general does seem to have very low priority. (Which becomes apparent when looking at the whole error/warning mess from a distance)  Using attributes seems pretty reasonable. I would probably go for a different naming like `[[constraint_failed("reason")]]` or `[[requirement_failed("reason")]]`

Comment: @non-user38741 Yes, unfortunately it looks like this is quite low prioritization. Note that the paper has a section _Bikeshedding_ which [bikesheds](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding) over a few alternatives, one of which is similar to your own, `constraint_failure_diagnostic`. As this is an EWG paper, even if it were to be accepted it would likely be modified to some extent, including the name for the attribute.

Comment: I don’t know what an “EWG status” is, but that paper was considered *in* 2018 and “rejected”—that is, new information (like “It’s 2021 and in practice concept error messages are still bad”) would be needed to consider it again.

Comment: @DavisHerring I couldn’t find any ”status” for the paper (rejected, withdrawn, ...?), and [the only reference I’ve found to it on open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/sd-1.htm) is that it is in _Subgroup: Evolution_. Do you have a reference for its rejection? If so, I will update this answer accordingly.

Comment: @dfri: Recently, papers have been given very brief [public statuses](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues); for older papers like this one, the references are unfortunately internal.

Comment: This feature, on concepts, would be particularly neat. It would help to accentuate them into their own being -- they feel too much like a template variable right now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can do right now, without the kind of new language feature that [dfri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63579321/2069064) points out, is just to write your own static assert.

In this case, to avoid repeating yourself, you can add a concept to check if you can instantiate a template:

```cpp
template <template <typename...> class Z,
    typename... Args>
concept can_instantiate = requires {
    typename Z<Args...>;
};
```

and then assert that you can create that alias first:

```cpp
static_assert(can_instantiate<BaseWrapper, C, Base>, "some message here");
using T2 = BaseWrapper<C,Base>;
```

Alternatively, you can move `BaseWrapper`'s constraints themselves to be static assertions:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename BaseType>
struct BaseWrapper {
    static_assert(is_base_of<BaseType, T>, "some message here");
};
```

This has the drawback of no longer being externally detectable - which may or may not be important in practice.

Comment: I'm not following. How is that supposed to work if the concept is part of a lib and a user tries to instantiate a template (or just call a function) with types that don't fit the requirement?

Comment: @non-user38741 How is what supposed to work if what is part of what? I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
template< typename T, typename V >
constexpr bool assert_is_same_v = 
    []{ static_assert(std::is_same_v<T,V>, "message here"); return true; }();
```

OR

```
template< typename T, typename V >
concept assert_is_same_v = 
    []{ static_assert(std::is_same_v<T,V>, "message here"); return true; }();
```

Then...

```
template< typename T >
requires assert_is_same_v<T,int>
void func(){}
```

I have been playing with the above code as a way to display messages.

Comment: The downside of this is that it is not a concept; it's just a `constexpr bool` variable template. It lacks any of the special functionality of a true concept, like subsumption rules. This `assert_is_same_v` will not be seen as equivalent to `same_as`, even though it logically should be. The tradeoff just isn't worth it to get an error message.