# implement a C++20 concept

Tags: c++, static-assert, concept

How can I programatically implement a concept as if it were an actual "interface"?

For example, I was trying recently to write a contigious iterator for a custom container. And because contigious iterators have a lot of traits, I wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything, so I used a static assert like the following:

```
struct CustomContainer
{
    struct Iterator
    {
        using iterator_category = std::contiguous_iterator_tag;
        /* Iterator impl */
    };
    static_assert(std::contiguous_iterator<Iterator>);
};
```

Problem with that is the compiler just says "static assertion failed" and doesn't give me a hint what is actually missing from my implementation to satisfy the concept.

So, is there a better approach to this that I should know about?

Comment: [At least *some* compilers do tell you what's wrong.](https://godbolt.org/z/a9s7jE4rn)

Comment: well, sadly MSVC doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do that currently with concept. they can only tell if a type meets constraints requirements or not.

source :

[How to make a concept fail with a custom error message (C++20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579067/how-to-make-a-concept-fail-with-a-custom-error-message-c20)

Comment: The standard does not specify error message content.  Only existence.  This is a QOI issue in MSVC.